# Blocking socket - detect state

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I am developing my first c/c++ application and using sockets. This application connects to server and reads image data sent from server, the image data is preceded by a few ints which are of interest like how much data to read.

The application is using blocking sockets as I didn't think having my thread just continuously looping was better when there was the option of blocking until the data was available.

My problem now is if the server just loses connection to network my application just sits there and i have no way of triggering a notification to the user or attempt a re-connection. I don't know how to check for state of connection.

Could somebody offer me a little advice as to how to solve my problem please?

thank you. I have pasted my readImageInt() function which shows how i am reading from socket. I am developing using linux device.

```
int readImageInt()
{

int nb, i;
union {
    long int whole;
    char bytes[4];
} v;
memset(v.bytes, 0x00, 4);
nb = recv(imagesock, v.bytes, 4, MSG_WAITALL);
if (nb == 0||nb == -1)
 {

    return -1;
 }
else
    {
    v.whole = ntohl(v.whole);

     return v.whole;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you creating the socket as `SOCK_STREAM`?

Comment: yes, imagesock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)

Comment: How come you are not using `IPPROTO_TCP`? I assume it is tcp.

Comment: first app Nick, is that a mistake then? i'll do some reading up on it but does it solve the problem mentioned?

Comment: It might, `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)`

Comment: thanks Nick, i now understand SOCK_STREAM and IPPROTO_TCP go together. It doesn't help this situation though.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`SO_RCVTIMEO`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html) [socket option](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) to break out of long blocking receive operation.

#### Edit 0:

Alternatively, you can use a polling call like [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html), [`poll(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or [`epoll_wait(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) if you are on Linux) with a timeout. That would allow you to break out of in-kernel wait to check, say, some user input telling you whether to continue waiting or bail.

The more reliable way to detect broken connection though is to *send* data if other side supports it - you'll get a signal or an error return (though on crashed remote end that might be on the order of minutes).

#### Edit 1:

Take a look at [`select_tut(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select_tut.2.html)

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, ideally I want to block until data is returned or a disconnection happens - is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions to use select, im trying to get my head around how to use select with my setup - what would i do in readimageint for example - loop contionusly in select with a timeout of 1 sec and then break out of loop and read if data is avilable or notify if error returned? I just thought that blocking at recv (no looping) was more efficient.

Comment: It is more efficient unless you want to break out early.

Comment: so I can use select without setting a timeout and it will return only if data is available or connection is closed?

Comment: Yes, but that's no different from blocking `recv()` - if remote end falls off the face of the net you will never know, unless you set a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using select function to check the state of your socket before receiving any data. See here for example http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/lr2/select.htm